Query Loop block display multiple post types
Is there a way to display multiple post types from the Query Loop block in Gutenberg/FSE? I am trying to show content in date order (most recent first) from multiple post types. For instance, include POST, PHOTO (this is a CPT), CAMERA ROLL (CPT).

